# Calling a View's method from its own View Controller, Not Working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller calling a method in its own view called closeMenu. closeMenu as seen below remove's a UIImageView called menu from the superView and sets it equal to nil. The method works when called from within the view but not when called from the View Controller

When calling the method, the view controller sees the UIImageView 'menu' as nil even though it is exists.

Any ideas on how to give the view controller the ability to remove menu from the superview and set it equal to nil?

View Controller:

```
     loadview {
        View *mainView = [[View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
        self.view = mainView;
        [mainView release];
     }

//Call closeMenu in View
[(View *)self.view closeMenu];
```

View:

```
menu = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self addSubview:menu];

-(void)closeMenu {
     NSLog(@"%@", menu);    //Displays: (null), only when called by controller
     if( menu != nil) {
           [menu removeFromSuperview];
           self.menu = nil;
     }
 }
```

When I create a button instance in the view with an action directed at the closeMenu method it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `menu` an outlet? If so, is it hooked up in IB? Have you loaded the nib where it's hooked up?

If not, where are you assigning to it? Is the controller giving the view its menu? If that's the case, has that happened yet? If the view creates or loads its own menu view, has *that* happened yet, if at all?

Comment: Not using IB, coding everything. Menu is initalized in the View, there is no mention of it in the view controller. Edited above to show where menu init

Answer (score 1):

Be assured that 'where' you call `-closeMenu` from makes no difference whatsoever. If your log statement prints null then your menu variable is null. This doesn't mean you haven't got an 'open' instance - just that your menu variable doesn't point to it.

You would need to post some more code for anyone to work out why this is happening as you have an error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: No, it works fine when assigned to a button instance in the view. But added information anyways.

Comment: It can make a difference if the view receives the `closeMenu` message before it receives a message that would cause it to create or load the menu view.

Comment: Have 2 buttons for the testing: 1 that sends the closeMenu method from the Controller then other button sends the method from the view. The View button closes the menu just fine, but the view controller does not.

'menu' is in the view's header file